# Как направить allure-results jest-тестов в ТестОпс?

Tags: jest, allure

На проекте используется jest-allure. После прогона тестов формируется папка allure-results. Задача в следующем: не устраивают локальные отчёты, требуется, чтобы после прогона юнит-тестов результаты о прохождении или падении теста отправлялись в Allure ТестОпс в конкретный тест. Таким образом связь необходимо организовать через id. [allure-jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-allure) не умеет, как я понимаю, id для теста - только в виде лейбла.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли уже известные решения для такой задачи?